# Spark mixing dynamic/static partitions

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

HAE been able to mix static and dynamic partitions while using pyspark? What I'd like to do is perform dynamic partitioning, then have the most granular partitioning level be static. The static partition would be an identifier for the ETL job, meaning it would need to be a static partition unless I was to add it as a column to every record in the data frame beforehand.

What I have right now is the following. It may not be optimal so recommendations are welcome.

```
dataFrame.repartition('year','month','day','hour').write.partitionBy('year','month','day','hour').mode('append').parquet(args['s3_dest'])
```

Somehow, I want to introduce an additional static partition so that records show up in s3 as:
s3://bucket/year=xxxx/month=xx/day=xx/hour=xx/executionId=xx

Where executionId is generated within the etl script.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `executionId` as a new column and append it to `partitionBy` list:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

executionId = ...

(dataFrame.withColumn('executionId', lit(executionId))
    .repartition('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour')  # No executionId here!
    .write.partitionBy('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'executionId')
    .mode('append').parquet(args['s3_dest']))
```